# Directive attribute used as input name

Tags: angular, angular-directive

If I have an attribute directive that binds as follows:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myselectiondirective]',
})

<ul myselectiondirective>
```

Is it possible to use that attribute as an input at the same time, as in:

```
<ul [myselectiondirective]="initialSelection">
```

If so, what would be the way to go? `[[myselectiondirective]]` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can find an exemple of this case in the official documentation. See https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#bind-to-an-input-alias

Comment: Yes, you can just do `[myselectiondirective]="value"` and then in the directive, use `@Input('myselectiondirective')` to get that value.

Comment: Either comment deserves to be an accepted answer.